# slideup row when an element in clicked to slidedown on a sibling row

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok, this is a bit complex.

this is the html:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(".col-sm-6 .practice .more").click( function() {
    $('.col-sm-6 .practice .more').not(this).closest(".practice").find(".info").removeClass('yes');
      $(this).closest(".practice").find(".info").toggleClass("yes");
        $('.col-sm-6 .more').not(this).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").removeClass('yesrow');
      $(this).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").toggleClass("yesrow");
     if($('.yes').length >0 ){
       var a = $(this).closest(".practice").find(".yes").html();
    var b = $(this).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice .info").html(a);
     }
    });
      let oldElement;
      $(".col-sm-6 .practice .more").click(function() {
        let currentElement = $(this)[0];
        if (currentElement === oldElement) {
        $(currentElement).closest(".row").removeClass('show');
          $(currentElement).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").slideUp('slow');
          currentElement = null;
        }
        else
        {
          $(currentElement).closest(".row").addClass('show');
           $(currentElement).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").slideDown('slow');
        }
        oldElement= currentElement;
      });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>


     <div id="wpv-view-layout-4457" class="js-wpv-view-layout js-wpv-layout-responsive js-wpv-view-layout-4457">
    
     
     
     
      
      <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="practice">
      <div class="pracimg">
    <img width="269" height="168" src="http://outofsite.co.il/klag/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plili-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <div class="pracinfo">
        <p><strong>סכסוכים אזרחיים מורכבים</strong></p>
        <span class="exinfo"><p>בקשר עם עסקאות בתחומים שונים, מייצג תאגידים בינלאומיים בהליכים המתנהלים נגדם בארץ ומסייע לעורכי הדין בסכסוכים המתנהלים נגד לקוחות המשרד בחו"ל. לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון עשיר בניהול הליכי ליטיגציה מורכבים. ניסיון זה משמש את המשרד בפרט ובהליכים אזרחיים מורכבים.</p>
    </span>
        <span class="more">קרא עוד &gt;</span>
      </div>
    <div class="info"><p><strong>סכסוכים אזרחיים מורכבים</strong></p>
      <p>ד"ר א. קלגסבלד ושות' מטפל בסכסוכים אזרחיים מורכבים בקשר עם עסקאות בתחומים שונים, מייצג תאגידים בינלאומיים בהליכים המתנהלים נגדם בארץ ומסייע לעורכי הדין הזרים בסכסוכים המתנהלים נגד לקוחות המשרד בחו"ל. לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון עשיר בניהול הליכי ליטיגציה מורכבים ניסיון זה משמש את המשרד בפרט בהליכים אזרחיים מורכבים.</p>
    <p>כך, למשל, המשרד מייצג את מר שלדון ג. אדלסון בסכסוך לגבי הבעלות על פעילות ההימורים במקאו ובסכסוך בקשר לעיתון "ישראלי" ולעיתון "ישראל היום", ‎את פרופ' שלמה בן חיים בתביעות לגבי בעלות בחברות טכנולוגיה עילית, את חברת Kia בסכסוך בקשר עם הפצת רכביה בישראל, ואת מר טום קפלן בסכסוך עם PCIC וגומא אגייר.</p>
    <p>ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו טיפלו במאבקי שליטה מורכבים בחברות גדולות, בסכסוכים בין בעלי המניות ובין נושאי משרה, בתביעות קיפוח מיעוט, בתביעות לאכיפת הסכמי מכר מניות ולביטול הסכמים כאלה ובסכסוכים מורכבים נוספים הנוגעים למרקם היחסים התאגידי. הליווי המשפטי הניתן על ידי המשרד בקשר עם סכסוכים אלה הוא ליווי כולל במסגרתו ד"ר קלגסבלד מופיע בערכאות משפטיות שונות, משתתף בישיבות דירקטוריון בארץ ובחו"ל, ונוטל חלק בישיבות הנהלה. כך, למשל, ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו ייצגו בסכסוכי שליטה בידיעות אחרונות, ברשת קלאב הוטל, בחברות פרץ בוני הנגב, בורגר קינג, קמור, טמפו, מרצדס ומדינול. כך למשל, המשרד ליווה את סכסוך בעלי המניות בתאגיד "סימנס", את הסכסוך בקשר לתאגיד אמבלייז, את חברת חבס השקעות בסכסוך עם יגאל אהובי, את קבוצת DSP בסכסוך עם קרנות הון סיכון ועוד.</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
      
      
       <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="practice">
      <div class="pracimg">
    <img width="269" height="168" src="http://outofsite.co.il/klag/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plili-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <div class="pracinfo">
        <p><strong>פלילי – עבירות צווארון לבן</strong></p>
        <span class="exinfo"><p>המשרד ליווה חשודים ונאשמים בביצוע עבירות צווארון לבן (ביניהם תאגידי ענק ובכירים בקהילה העסקית) הליווי ניתן משלב הליכי החקירה דרך הליכי השימוע וייצוג בהליך הפלילי עצמו ועד להכרעות דין תקדימיות.</p>
    </span>
        <span class="more">קרא עוד &gt;</span>
      </div>
    <div class="info"><p><strong>פלילי – עבירות צווארון לבן</strong></p>
      <p>המשרד ליווה חשודים ונאשמים בביצוע עבירות צווארון לבן (ביניהם תאגידי ענק ובכירים בקהילה העסקית) הליווי ניתן משלב הליכי החקירה דרך הליכי השימוע וייצוג בהליך הפלילי עצמו ועד להכרעות דין תקדימיות. ד"ר קלגסבלד ייצג את אריאל שרון בפרשת האי היווני ובפרשת סיריל קרן, את משפחת רקאנטי, בנק דיסקונט ו I.D.B במשפט הבנקאים ואת עופר נמרודי בקשר עם חברותו בדירקטוריון בעקבות הרשעה פלילית. ד"ר קלגסבלד אחראי לזיכוים של מי שהואשמו בעבירות חמורות: י.ל.ר שוקי הון ובטוחה בפרשת באומל ומר מאיר הדר בפרשת פריון וכן את עו"ד ישראל שמעונוב בפרשת תמיר פישמן.</p>
    <p>‎בנוסף המשרד מלווה תאגידים שהם נפגעי עבירות צווארון לבן ומסייע להם בהיבטים של ההליכים הפלילים והאזרחיים הקשורים בביצוע העבירות האמורות ביניהם קבוצת הראל בקשר עם פרשת המעילה של גיא ויסמן, בית ההשקעות פסגות בקשר עם פרשת הרצת המניות, בזק ופלאפון בפרשת הסוס הטרויאני ובנק הפועלים בפרשת הלבנת ההון.</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
              <div class="outerpractice"><div class="info"></div></div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="practice">
      <div class="pracimg">
    <img width="269" height="168" src="http://outofsite.co.il/klag/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plili-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <div class="pracinfo">
        <p><strong>משפט מנהלי, משפט חוקתי וועדות חקירה</strong></p>
        <span class="exinfo"><p>לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון אקדמי עשיר בתחומי משפט אלה: ד"ר קלגסבלד שימש כמרצה למשפט חוקתי במוסדות אקדמיים מובילים וחיבר את הספר “ועדות חקירה ממלכתיות” (2001).</p>
    </span>
        <span class="more">קרא עוד &gt;</span>
      </div>
    <div class="info"><p><strong>משפט מנהלי, משפט חוקתי וועדות חקירה</strong></p>
      <p>לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון אקדמי עשיר בתחומי משפט אלה: ד"ר קלגסבלד שימש כמרצה למשפט חוקתי במוסדות אקדמיים מובילים וחיבר את הספר “ועדות חקירה ממלכתיות” (2001). ד"ר קלגסבלד גם אחראי לפרסומים בכתבי עת מובילים בינהם "הערה להיקף חסינותו של נשיא המדינה" עיוני משפט ז (תשל"ט) 238, "כתב הקלה ורשיון חופש" עיוני משפט ט (תשמ"ג) 211, "The Kahan Commission of Inquiry" (1983), Public Law, "עבירה פלילית ומניעה מוקדמת" פלילים ב (תשנ"א) 1991, "תפקיד ציבורי, עבר פלילי וראיה מנהלית" המשפט (תשנ"ה) 93, "צמצום זכות הטיעון בפני ועדות חקירה" משפט וממשל (תשנ"ח) 751, "סתירה לחוק-יסוד" הפרקליט (תשס"ו) 293 ו"מהלכת רובינשטיין עד ספר רובינשטיין" – על פירושו העדכני של סעיף 4 לחוק-יסוד: הכנסת" משפט ועסקים (תשע"ב), 183.</p>
    <p>ניסיון אקדמי זה תורגם לניהול מאבקים בתחומי משפט אלה הן בקשר עם הליכי בחירות (ייצוג שאול מופז בקשר עם הזכות להיבחר וייצוג טל זילברשטיין בקשר עם פרשת "עמותת ברק") והן עבור גופים מרכזיים במשק וביניהם גם גופי תקשורת גדולים (החקיקה בעניין בעלות זרה על עיתון ישראלי ומכרזי התקשורת של ערוץ 10 וערוץ החדשות). בנוסף ד"ר קלגסבלד נטל חלק במאבקים ציבוריים בעלי חשיבות עקרונית: ייצוג סיעות בעיריית תל-אביב בקשר עם חברות של אישה בגוף הבוחר רב עיר, ייצוג ח"כ צבן בקשר עם פרשת הכספים הייחודים, ייצוג חוקה לישראל בקשר עם אפליה בפטורי מס וייצוג נעמת בקשר עם שיטת הבחירות בהסתדרות.</p>
    <p>ד"ר קלגסבלד מייצג תדיר ראשי ממשלה, שרים ודמויות מפתח ציבוריות בועדות חקירה ממלכתיות (מר בנימין נתניהו בועדת טירקל בקשר עם המשט לעזה, מפקד היחידה לאבטחת אישים בועדת שמגר בקשר עם רצח יצחק רבין, מר אהוד ברק בועדת אור בקשר עם אירועי אוקטובר 2000 ומר יצחק אהרונוביץ בועדת זיילר בקשר עם פעילות משטרת ישראל ופרקליטות המדינה בפרשת האחים פריניאן).</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
      
      
       <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="practice">
      <div class="pracimg">
    <img width="269" height="168" src="http://outofsite.co.il/klag/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plili-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <div class="pracinfo">
        <p><strong>הגבלים עסקיים</strong></p>
        <span class="exinfo"><p>תחום ההגבלים העסקיים, המשלב התמחויות משפטיות וכלכליות, הוא מתחומי המשפט הסבוכים והמורכבים ביותר. לתחום משפטי זה השפעה מכרעת על התנהלות יומיות של חברות ומנהלים במשק הישראלי.</p>
    </span>
        <span class="more">קרא עוד &gt;</span>
      </div>
    <div class="info"><p><strong>הגבלים עסקיים</strong></p>
      <p>תחום ההגבלים העסקיים, המשלב התמחויות משפטיות וכלכליות, הוא מתחומי המשפט הסבוכים והמורכבים ביותר. לתחום משפטי זה השפעה מכרעת על התנהלות יומיות של חברות ומנהלים במשק הישראלי.<br>
    לתחום ההגבלים העסקיים היבטים אזרחיים ופליליים.</p>
    <p>ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו אחראים להלכות מרכזיות בתחום ההגבלים העסקיים בתחום האזרחי, כמו הלכת שף הים, בתחום הפלילי, כמו בפרשת רמזורים ופרשת קרטל הבשר של תנובה. המשרד מעניק ייעוץ בהיבטים אזרחיים ופליליים של הסדרים כובלים, מיזוגים ומונופולים ומייצג תאגידים אלה מול הרשויות השונות ובערכאות משפטיות. כך, למשל, המשרד טיפל בהיבטים שונים של מונופול בסכיני הגילוח ג'ילט ובמיזוג חברות הדלק סונול ודור אלון.</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
              <div class="outerpractice"><div class="info"></div></div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="practice">
      <div class="pracimg">
    <img width="269" height="168" src="http://outofsite.co.il/klag/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plili-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <div class="pracinfo">
        <p><strong>סכסוכי שליטה בחברות</strong></p>
        <span class="exinfo"><p>לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון אקדמי עשיר בתחומי משפט אלה: ד"ר קלגסבלד שימש כמרצה למשפט חוקתי במוסדות אקדמיים מובילים וחיבר את הספר “ועדות חקירה ממלכתיות” (2001).</p>
    </span>
        <span class="more">קרא עוד &gt;</span>
      </div>
    <div class="info"><p><strong>סכסוכי שליטה בחברות</strong></p>
      <p>ד"ר א. קלגסבלד ושות' מטפל בסכסוכים אזרחיים מורכבים בקשר עם עסקאות בתחומים שונים, מייצג תאגידים בינלאומיים בהליכים המתנהלים נגדם בארץ ומסייע לעורכי הדין הזרים בסכסוכים המתנהלים נגד לקוחות המשרד בחו"ל. לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון עשיר בניהול הליכי ליטיגציה מורכבים ניסיון זה משמש את המשרד בפרט בהליכים אזרחיים מורכבים.</p>
    <p>כך, למשל, המשרד מייצג את מר שלדון ג. אדלסון בסכסוך לגבי הבעלות על פעילות ההימורים במקאו ובסכסוך בקשר לעיתון "ישראלי" ולעיתון "ישראל היום", ‎את פרופ' שלמה בן חיים בתביעות לגבי בעלות בחברות טכנולוגיה עילית, את חברת Kia בסכסוך בקשר עם הפצת רכביה בישראל, ואת מר טום קפלן בסכסוך עם PCIC וגומא אגייר.</p>
    <p>ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו טיפלו במאבקי שליטה מורכבים בחברות גדולות, בסכסוכים בין בעלי המניות ובין נושאי משרה, בתביעות קיפוח מיעוט, בתביעות לאכיפת הסכמי מכר מניות ולביטול הסכמים כאלה ובסכסוכים מורכבים נוספים הנוגעים למרקם היחסים התאגידי. הליווי המשפטי הניתן על ידי המשרד בקשר עם סכסוכים אלה הוא ליווי כולל במסגרתו ד"ר קלגסבלד מופיע בערכאות משפטיות שונות, משתתף בישיבות דירקטוריון בארץ ובחו"ל, ונוטל חלק בישיבות הנהלה. כך, למשל, ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו ייצגו בסכסוכי שליטה בידיעות אחרונות, ברשת קלאב הוטל, בחברות פרץ בוני הנגב, בורגר קינג, קמור, טמפו, מרצדס ומדינול. כך למשל, המשרד ליווה את סכסוך בעלי המניות בתאגיד "סימנס", את הסכסוך בקשר לתאגיד אמבלייז, את חברת חבס השקעות בסכסוך עם יגאל אהובי, את קבוצת DSP בסכסוך עם קרנות הון סיכון ועוד.</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
      
      
       <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="practice">
      <div class="pracimg">
    <img width="269" height="168" src="http://outofsite.co.il/klag/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/plili-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="">
        </div>
      <div class="pracinfo">
        <p><strong>מעמד אישי</strong></p>
        <span class="exinfo"><p>לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון אקדמי עשיר בתחומי משפט אלה: ד"ר קלגסבלד שימש כמרצה למשפט חוקתי במוסדות אקדמיים מובילים וחיבר את הספר “ועדות חקירה ממלכתיות” (2001).</p>
    </span>
        <span class="more">קרא עוד &gt;</span>
      </div>
    <div class="info"><p><strong>מעמד אישי</strong></p>
      <p>ד"ר א. קלגסבלד ושות' מטפל בסכסוכים אזרחיים מורכבים בקשר עם עסקאות בתחומים שונים, מייצג תאגידים בינלאומיים בהליכים המתנהלים נגדם בארץ ומסייע לעורכי הדין הזרים בסכסוכים המתנהלים נגד לקוחות המשרד בחו"ל. לד"ר קלגסבלד ניסיון עשיר בניהול הליכי ליטיגציה מורכבים ניסיון זה משמש את המשרד בפרט בהליכים אזרחיים מורכבים.</p>
    <p>כך, למשל, המשרד מייצג את מר שלדון ג. אדלסון בסכסוך לגבי הבעלות על פעילות ההימורים במקאו ובסכסוך בקשר לעיתון "ישראלי" ולעיתון "ישראל היום", ‎את פרופ' שלמה בן חיים בתביעות לגבי בעלות בחברות טכנולוגיה עילית, את חברת Kia בסכסוך בקשר עם הפצת רכביה בישראל, ואת מר טום קפלן בסכסוך עם PCIC וגומא אגייר.</p>
    <p>ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו טיפלו במאבקי שליטה מורכבים בחברות גדולות, בסכסוכים בין בעלי המניות ובין נושאי משרה, בתביעות קיפוח מיעוט, בתביעות לאכיפת הסכמי מכר מניות ולביטול הסכמים כאלה ובסכסוכים מורכבים נוספים הנוגעים למרקם היחסים התאגידי. הליווי המשפטי הניתן על ידי המשרד בקשר עם סכסוכים אלה הוא ליווי כולל במסגרתו ד"ר קלגסבלד מופיע בערכאות משפטיות שונות, משתתף בישיבות דירקטוריון בארץ ובחו"ל, ונוטל חלק בישיבות הנהלה. כך, למשל, ד"ר קלגסבלד וצוותו ייצגו בסכסוכי שליטה בידיעות אחרונות, ברשת קלאב הוטל, בחברות פרץ בוני הנגב, בורגר קינג, קמור, טמפו, מרצדס ומדינול. כך למשל, המשרד ליווה את סכסוך בעלי המניות בתאגיד "סימנס", את הסכסוך בקשר לתאגיד אמבלייז, את חברת חבס השקעות בסכסוך עם יגאל אהובי, את קבוצת DSP בסכסוך עם קרנות הון סיכון ועוד.</p>
    </div>
    </div></div>
              <div class="outerpractice"><div class="info"></div></div>
      </div>
      
     
    
     
    </div>





</html>
```

basically, 2 rows, inside each row 2 columns, and there's an extra div after the columns to which i am copying the extended text (which is initially hidden) after clicking "read more", with this jquery:

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/ojef6gxz/5/
and here's where i'm trying to do this with the actual texts (in hebrew):
http://outofsite.co.il/klag/test/

what i'm trying to do is: when i press "read more" and the outer div opens, and then i press "read more" on the sibling row - i want the first child outer row to close.  like here:

http://kelim.org.il/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D/

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got it!

added this:

```
$(this).closest(".row").siblings().find(".outerpractice").slideUp("slow");
```

to the code, which now looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$(".col-sm-6 .practice .more").click( function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").siblings().find(".outerpractice").slideUp("slow"); 
  $('.col-sm-6 .practice .more').not(this).closest(".practice").find(".info").removeClass('yes');
  $(this).closest(".practice").find(".info").toggleClass("yes");
    $('.col-sm-6 .more').not(this).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").removeClass('yesrow');
  $(this).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").toggleClass("yesrow");
 if($('.yes').length >0 ){
   var a = $(this).closest(".practice").find(".yes").html();
var b = $(this).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice .info").html(a);
 }

});
  let oldElement;
  $(".col-sm-6 .practice .more").click(function() {
    let currentElement = $(this)[0];
    if (currentElement === oldElement) {
    $(currentElement).closest(".row").removeClass('show');
      $(currentElement).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").slideUp('slow');
      currentElement = null;
    }
    else
    {
      $(currentElement).closest(".row").addClass('show');
       $(currentElement).closest(".row").find(".outerpractice").slideDown('slow');
    }
    oldElement= currentElement;

  });
});
```

and it works.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/g86wds4r/